# numeric fields added with single quote in jasper generated excel file

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm designing a jasper report with the field type & text field type as double.
When run the jrxml file using jasperreports4.7.jar for excel format,
it'll add a single quote in numeric columns.
so i can't do any numeric manipulation in excel.but same is working fine in jasperreports3.jar.

is anyone facing the same issue?
pls help me

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to define the field you want to print as an Integer or Double. (You must set your Report to java)

If I do not know yet what type of field is comming I am making, lets say 3 fields, one String, one Integer, one Double. Then I pass the info the what it is dynamically to another -meta-field.
In the designer I lay all 3 fields over each other. Seems to work.